# Can robocopy be used to delete files from the destination, 30 days after deletion from the source?

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy

I'm implementing a daily backup for active projects of a digitization lab. When projects become inactive, files are manually moved to permanent storage, so this is truly just backing up. Techs all have a data partition on their workstations to which they save their daily work on active projects. Within a PowerShell script, I'm using robocopy to perform a recurrsive backup (not a mirror).

I don't want to mirror because I want a insurance policy against accidental deletions, human error, and equipment failures. But, I need a way to manage backups so they don't grow out of hand. Basically, I'd like to use the `/PURGE` parameter, with a 30-day delay, to delete files that haven't been in the source for over 30 days.

There are a lot of robocopy examples on the web, but I couldn't find one that does this. I think that might be because I'm asking something that's not possible with robocopy. If that's true, my next tactic would be to process my log files somehow, but that is getting into more time than I want to spend.

Comment: How do you know whether source files haven't been used in a project?  How are you tracking the source has been deleted and when?

Comment: I think you'd need to process the log files. How do you know if a file has been missing for 30 days from the source? Created or modified dates would not work.

Comment: Not sure how to help you with that but in the past, I used allwaysync to take recursive backups. You can configure it to "move" the deleted files when it does is one way sync to a special folder for a number of version / amount of time. It might be worth a look at. Also, there's (I assume) a complete team that worked to develop it and you can probably rely on it more.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 This is manual. There's a whole project management piece to this and moving the files is part of closing out a project. Right now, someone (a tech or the supervisor) is moving files out into the permanent storage location. (Soon to be using robocopy, not yet.)

Comment: Upon reflection, adding on to that might be the most pragmatic approach. A naming convention that would allow the supervisor to run a command to recursively delete directories accross all the backups having to do with the project, as a final step, 30-days after the files have been moved to permenant storage. Not as automated as I'd hoped, but a comprimise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Robocopy cannot do this. You need to be able to track the files.